# "The directory name /app/Views/ is invalid" on ASP.NET Core deployment using docker

Tags: linux, docker, asp.net-core, publish, asp.net-core-1.0

I followed [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stevelasker/2016/09/29/building-optimized-docker-images-with-asp-net-core/) article to setup a performant ASP.NET Core deployment using Docker. This works until I try to start the container using `docker run` which calls `dotnet MyAppName.dll` There I got an exception, that the **View** path is not existing:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentException: The directory name /app/Views/ is invalid.

And thats true, cause in the folder created by `dotnet publish` area only dll  files and no View folder:

```
user@server:/etc/jenkins/workspace/App# ll publish-output | grep View
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 237K Aug 31 19:26 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll
```

I cant understand this, cause the View folder is included in the `publishOptions` like wwwroot too, which is also missing:

```
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views/**/*.cshtml",
      "Areas/**/*.cshtml"
    ]
  },
```

I also tried `"Views"` instead of `"Views/**/*.cshtml"` but not working. In my understanding, those `publishOptions` should result in copying those folders to the publishing-directory when using `dotnet publish`.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using the `microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.0.1` image for building and `microsoft/aspnetcore:1.0.1` for starting the app like recommended as best practice in the article.

**UPDATE**
Seems to be a problem on linux only. My Win10 development machine works fine, there I get any view-folders published from the main app and areas as expected.

**UPDATE #2** Using the examples on the [aspnetcore-build repo](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore-build/) on the docker hub, its not working too.

**UPDATE #3** I created a new ASP.NET Core MVC project on my Windows 10 development machine using Visual Studio, then transferred it to the linux box: Not working, the views are missing.

**UPDATE #4** Created a new app using `dotnet new -t web` directly on the linux box: Works like expected!

**UPDATE #5** I ran `dotnet new -t web` on the Windows machine, moved the created folder to the linux server: Not working - Strange...

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a missing space in the documentation before the dot, which should refer the current folder.

**Wrong (1:1 copy from the description of the docker image)**

```
RUN dotnet publish --output /out/. --configuration Release
```

**Correct**

```
RUN dotnet publish --output /out/ . --configuration Release
```

Here is the space missing: --output /out/**{Space}**.